# How to assign correct field type?

Tags: apex, visualforce

In trying to create `Contact` records, I am getting errors like:

> Illegal assignment from Integer to String at line 9 column 9

How can I determine the correct type and construct it? For example the `MobilePhone` and `Birthdate` fields are tripping me up.

**Snippet**

```
conTest.firstName='Sachin';
conTest.lastname='Goyal';
conTest.Salutation='Mr';
//conTest.homephone=976;
conTest.mobilephone=223;
conTest.accountid=234;
conTest.otherphone=2332;
conTest.title='sach';
conTest.fax=34;
conTest.department=10;
conTest.email='sachin@gmail.com';
conTest.birthdate='13-12-90';
conTest.assistantname='XYZ';
conTest.reportstoid=123;
conTest.assistantphone=2345;
conTest.leadsource='zz';
conTest.mailingstreet='shastri nagar';
conTest.otherstreet='vaishali';
conTest.mailingcity='ajmer';
conTest.othercity='jaipur';
conTest.mailingstate='rajastha';
conTest.otherstate='mp';
conTest.mailingpostalcode=234;
conTest.otherpostalcode=322;
conTest.mailingcountry='India';
conTest.othercountry='africa';
conTest.Languages__c='english';
conTest.Level__c='higher';
conTest.description='abc';
insert conTest;
```

Comment: You need to tell us which one is line 9. I guess your issue is when you do `conTest.mobilephone=223;` or `conTest.fax = 34`. Phones tend to be strings, and you're assigning an Integer there instead. Use `conTest.mobilephone='223';` (note the quotes surrounding '233')

Comment: You may find similar issues with other fields like  `assistantphone`, `reporsttoid`, `birthdate`. You need to be aware of basic data types before making an assignment.

Comment: how to assign birthdate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper types for the fields like mobilephone,otherphone,fax,description,postalcode etc..

```
Contact conTest = new Contact();
    conTest.firstName='Sachin'; 
    conTest.lastname='Goyal'; 
    conTest.Salutation='Mr'; 
    //conTest.homephone=976; 
    conTest.mobilephone='223'; 
    conTest.otherphone='2332'; 
    conTest.title='sach'; 
    conTest.fax='34'; 
    conTest.department='10'; 
    conTest.email='sachin@gmail.com';
    conTest.birthdate=date.parse('12/13/90'); 
    conTest.assistantname='XYZ'; 
    conTest.assistantphone='2345'; 
    conTest.leadsource='zz'; 
    conTest.mailingstreet='shastri nagar'; 
    conTest.otherstreet='vaishali'; 
    conTest.mailingcity='ajmer'; 
    conTest.othercity='jaipur'; 
    conTest.mailingstate='rajastha'; 
    conTest.otherstate='mp'; 
    conTest.mailingpostalcode='234'; 
    conTest.otherpostalcode='322'; 
    conTest.mailingcountry='India'; 
    conTest.othercountry='africa'; 
    conTest.description='abc'; 
    insert conTest;
```

Comment: how to assign birthdate?

Comment: You can parse the date string like this : date.parse('mm/dd/yyyy');  conTest.birthdate=date.parse('12/13/90');